# Proving that a quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezoid if and only if the diagonals are congruent.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

I would like a proof to [a Theorem (via OnlineMathLearning.com)](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/image-files/theorem-trapezoid.png) I found:

> A quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezoid if and only if the diagonals are congruent.

And more specifically, Wikipedia's ["Isosceles trapezoid" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid?wprov=sfla1) says:

> (An isosceles trapezoid is a) trapezoid in which both legs and both base angles are of equal measure.

If necessary, assume that the diagonals bisect the base angles.

I can bring more sources that simply state the properties of an isosceles trapezoid that corroborate the above claims, but no proofs.

I am really struggling finding any proof for the definition of an isosceles trapezoid (and especially for a proof that only starts with the assumption that the diagonals of the quadrilateral are congruent and/or that they bisect the base angles).

Comment: What are the base angles? A quadrilateral (even one with congruent diagonals) does not have a preferred base.

Comment: I suspect that the source *intended* to state that "A **trapezoid** is an isosceles trapezoid if and only if the diagonals are congruent" (not "A **quadrilateral** is ..."). Likewise for the other theorems listed in that image. Otherwise, the statements simply aren't true. (Note that Theorem $1$ uses the term "legs", which doesn't apply to general quadrilaterals.)

Answer (score 1):

Label the trapezoid as the shown below. The base of the quadrilateral is $\overline{AD}$. The lengths of the sides $\overline{AB},\overline{BC},\overline{CD},\overline{AD}$ are respectively $b,c,d$, and $a$. The diagonals $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$ both have length $r$. Angles $\angle BAC$ and $\angle CAD$ are both $\alpha$, while $\angle ADB$ and $\angle BDC$ are both $\beta$.

[image: diagram]

Now because of how we define the "inside" of the quadrilateral, it must be the case that $2\alpha<\pi$ and $2\beta<\pi$. Furthermore, since $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$ must intersect, $2\alpha+\beta<\pi$. Likewise, $\alpha+2\beta<\pi$.

This valid region for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is shown below, excluding the boundary.

[image]

Note that because of this range of allowable values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the sines and cosines of these angles are positive.

Now, by equating expressions for the positions of points $B$ and $C$, we get the following equations.

$$\begin{align*}
r\cos\alpha&=a-d\cos2\beta & &(1)\\
b\cos2\alpha&=a-r\cos\beta & &(2)\\
r\sin\alpha&=d\sin2\beta & &(3)\\
a\sin2\alpha&=r\sin\beta & &(4)\\
\end{align*}$$

Rearranging $(1)$
$$a-r\cos\alpha=d\cos2\beta$$

Dividing by $(3)$
$$\frac{a-r\cos\alpha}{r\sin\alpha}=\frac{d\cos2\beta}{d\sin2\beta}$$

Solving for $r$
$$a-r\cos\alpha=r\sin\alpha\cot2\beta$$

$$r=\frac{a}{\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\cot2\beta}$$

Solving $(2)$ and $(4)$ for $r$
$$r=\frac{a}{\cos\beta+\sin\beta\cot2\alpha}$$

Combining these equations

$$\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\cot2\beta=\cos\beta+\sin\beta\cot2\alpha$$

Multiplying by $\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta$

$$\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta\cos\alpha+\sin2\alpha\cos2\beta\sin\alpha\\=\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta\cos\beta+\cos2\alpha\sin2\beta\sin\beta$$

Applying double angle theorems
$$4\sin\alpha\cos^2\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta+(1-2\sin^2\beta)2\sin^2\alpha\cos\alpha\\=4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos^2\beta+(1-2\sin^2\alpha)2\sin^2\beta\cos\beta$$

Distributing and factoring

$$4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)-4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)\\+2(1-\cos^2\alpha)\cos\alpha-2(1-\cos^2\beta)\cos\beta=0$$

$$4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)-4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)\\+2(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)-2(\cos^3\alpha-\cos^3\beta)=0$$

$$(4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta-4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta+2\\-2(\cos^2\alpha+\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\cos^2\beta))(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)=0$$

Now

$$(4\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\beta-4\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta+2-2(\cos^2\alpha+\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\cos^2\beta))<0$$

for all $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the legal range†. (It is exactly zero at $\alpha=0,\beta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and vice versa.) This means that

$$\cos\alpha-\cos\beta=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \alpha=\beta$$

Now clearly the base angles $2\alpha$ and $2\beta$ are equal. By SAS congruence, we get that $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle DCA$ are congruent. Therefore the base side lengths $b$ and $d$ are equal.

---

†[Verified graphically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSsh8.png). A full proof would likely include function maximization to show that the expression does not exceed $0$.

Comment: I am absolutely blown away by your proof, and am *tremendously* grateful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Old Answer: Question was asked without angle bisection constraint.**

The diagonals of a quadrilateral being congruent is not sufficient to prove that the quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezoid. Consider the quadrilateral shown below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, left out a detail: If neccesary, assume that the diagonals bisect the base angles. Edited.

Comment: Also, according to the source I just added (where I was coming from in asking the question), "a quadrilateral is an isosceles trapezoid if and only if the diagonals are congruent".